# How to check the date in object elements with the date in one element in the same object in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I am trying to check the date of all elements in the objects with one reference element and keep the ones that are within one year of the reference element

```
[
  {
    "_id": "102",
    "items": [
      {
        "p_id": "102",
        "e_date": "2017-04-01T00:00:00.000",
        "h_val": 4,
        
      },
      {
        "p_id1": "102",
        "e_date1": "2004-05-01T00:00:00.000",
        "s_val": 87,
        "d_val": 58
      },
      {
        "p_id1": "102",
        "e_date1": "2016-09-01T00:00:00.000",
        "s_val": 81,
        "d_val": 62
      }
    ],
    "count": 3
  }
]
```

For example in the above collection, in document 102 I want to keep the 3rd element, since its within 1 year of the first element but get rid of the 2nd element.

I have tried:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "items": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$items",
          "as": "item",
          "cond": {
            "$and": [
              {
                "$lte": [
                  {
                    "$divide": [
                      {
                        "$subtract": [
                          {
                            "$dateFromString": {
                              "dateString": "$$item.e_date"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "$dateFromString": {
                              "dateString": "$$item.e_date1"
                            }
                          },
                          
                        ]
                      },
                      86400000,
                      
                    ]
                  },
                  400,
                  
                ]
              },
              {
                "$gte": [
                  {
                    "$divide": [
                      {
                        "$subtract": [
                          {
                            "$dateFromString": {
                              "dateString": "$$item.e_date"
                            }
                          },
                          {
                            "$dateFromString": {
                              "dateString": "$$item.e_date1"
                            }
                          },
                          
                        ]
                      },
                      86400000,
                      
                    ]
                  },
                  0,
                  
                ]
              },
              
            ]
          },
          
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first element in the array will always be the reference, you could:

- $addFields to select the reference element
- $project using $filter

  - use $dateDiff and $dateFromString to get the difference between the dates in years
  - use $abs and $lte to limit to 1 year before or after the reference date

Sample code:

```
[
  {$addFields: {
      ref: {$arrayElemAt: ["$items",0]}}
  },
  {$project: {
      items: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$items",
          as: "item",
          cond: {
            $lte: [
              {$abs: {
                  $dateDiff: {
                    startDate: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$ref.e_date"}},
                    endDate: {$dateFromString: {dateString: "$$item.e_date"}},
                    unit: "year"
                  }
              }},
              1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/pliDQEmPZP2)

Comment: Great. I will need to remove abs because I am trying to check for variable intervals before and after the reference and there might be multiple references. I will play around your solution. Thanks.